# How does the Rails migration `change` method reverse its operations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have the following migration:

```
class AddMyColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :my_table, :my_new_column, :bigint
    add_foreign_key :my_table, :my_other_table, column: :my_new_column
    add_index :my_table, :my_new_column
  end
end
```

When reversing this migration, I see this error:

`Mysql2::Error: Cannot drop index 'index_my_table_on_my_new_column': needed in a foreign key constraint`

The [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method) explicitly says that a `change` migration using these actions should be reversible.

Re-ordering the `add_foreign_key` and `add_index` actions (or in this case, using `add_reference`) allows the migration to reverse successfully. However, this seems to contradict the documentation that states:

> Active Record knows how to reverse a migration's actions automatically... [when using] actions that `change` supports. If you're going to need to use any other methods, you should use reversible or write the up and down methods instead of using the change method

`add_column` `add_foreign_key` & `add_index` are all supported actions.

Does the `change` method perform any analysis of the actions in order to reverse them appropriately? Or does it simply apply them in the reverse order? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: can you try changing the order of lines, put `add_foreign_index` last?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but that's not really the question - the question is about Rails' ability to "reverse a migration's actions automatically".

Comment: And my answer suggests that to be able to revert operations, a migration has to be written correctly. `up` runs from top to bottom, and I bet that `down` runs in the opposite direction. At the moment you try to remove an index required for a foreign key before dropping that f-key. Please try what I suggested before explaining your question to me :)

Comment: Your `add_foreign_key` does not reference `my_new_column` so I am not sure how you are getting that error (did you possibly over obfuscate the post?)

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Can you define (or reference documentation about) what "written correctly" means? Note that the migration runs just fine in the `up` direction.

Sorry my question wasn't clear, but you didn't really provide any information about what I'm interested in - hence my attempt to explain the question to you. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks! Yes, that was an obfuscation error. Fixed.

Comment: Most people, most of the time perform a single operation in their migration. You did three operations. Rails is cool and stuff, but it's not magic, it can't "perform any analysis of the actions". It can however run them in reverse, and use inverse methods during down migration. Alex already provided the links, and I can only encourage you to read Rails source code. It made me a much better developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the change method perform any analysis of the actions in order to reverse them appropriately?

There is a class that's responsible for reversing known methods:
*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration/CommandRecorder.html#method-i-inverse_of*

---

> Or does it simply apply them in the reverse order? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Migration methods are executed from bottom up inside the `change` method (which you can just see in the log).

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration/CommandRecorder.html#method-i-revert*

> While executing the given block, the recorded will be in reverting mode. All commands recorded will end up being recorded **reverted and in reverse order**.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a foreign key in a migration using MySQL, if an index does not exist, it will be added automatically.

> MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an index is created.

Since you have added the index manually below, the rollback of your migration is trying to delete it but your use of foreign key requires it.

If you only delete the foreign key, the index will be deleted and you will be able to execute your rollback.

[MYSQL FK and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20requires%20that%20foreign%20key,column%2C%20an%20index%20is%20created.&text=Information%20about%20foreign%20keys%20on,tables%2C%20in%20the%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA%20database.)